# SWT TabFolder vertical orientation

Tags: eclipse, swt

Currently SWT's TabFolder supports only the TOP and BOTTOM styles, ie. it will only draw the tabs horizontally along the top or bottom of the control. This is unlike Swing's JTabbedPane, which gives the option of also orienting the tabs vertically, along the side of the control.

Can anyone suggest any workarounds to achieve a vertical orientation in SWT? Any suggestions of custom or 3rd-party components (or other alternative) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any SWT-compatible controls like that, but you could build your own alternative using a [StackLayout](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StackLayout.html) and some control(s) to switch between the different "panels." Here's a simple [example SWT Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet249.java).

You could also look at the code for [CTabFolder](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.html) and see if it would be straightforward to modify it to suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks, a custom component based on a StackLayout looks feasible. Modifying CTabFolder look less than straightforward (or at least fairly unpleasant :-)).